# "how update entities in mvc2 whereas database update"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I made project in mvc2.

I made database in Sql server.

I am fetching data through **entity  framework**. Then I made entities, and some controller classes.

Now when i add one more table in database, and deploy to server then the entities are showing of the old tables

so please how i also update entities without reconstruct entities

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are talking about data migration after a model change. This is not currently support. You can how ever create a custom database initializer and override the seed methods to manually migrate data.

Or simpler do not initialize the database and make the changes to the data model through SSMS

Comment: please can you give me in some more detail, or any link to follow

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of some of the features of "Code First" in EF4.1 to create entities to match your database, even if you don't use it to create your database.  That way the entities will automatically be created from your classes.

[Using EF Code First With an Existing Database](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx)